# Find $x$ and $y$ such that $x^2+10x+120y$ is the smallest

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have not had a math course in over 10 years. I'm really sorry. It is probably super trivial. Anyway, i know that $x+y=80$. How do I choose $x$ and $y$ such that $x^2+10x+120y$ is the smallest possible value?

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be done with an easier way..

```
  let   y=80-x
  and let E=x^2 +10x +120(80-x)
          E=x^2 -110x +9600
          E=(x-55)^2 -(55)^2 +9600
  Since x is a real number,
     for all x,  (x-55)^2 >=0
  Since we need to get the minimum value for E
     We will get that minimum value when (x-55)^2=0
```

for that x = 55 and then y =25

Comment: Nice, but do learn to type LaTeX. You can search for MathExchange LaTeX guide to get started.

Comment: Thanks a lot...sure I will...I searched a way on google..but not found..thankss

Comment: Searching for the phrase gives the guide as the first result, though something was wrong with me as I meant to type "StackExchange" lol..

Answer (score 0):

Since $y=80-x$, substitute that into $x^2+10x+120y$ and simplify. Then you have a quadratic function which you can minimize either using calculus or by knowing that the apex of the parabola $ax^2+bx+c$ is at $x=-b/2a$.

Answer (score 0):

We rewrite the expression as a function of two variables
$$f(x,y)=x^2+10x+120y$$

Now we use $y=80-x$ to eliminate y in the function and to get a fuction of one variable

$$f(x)=x^2+10x+120(80-x)$$
$$f(x)=x^2-110x+9600$$

Now this is a parabola, you can finde the minimum by differentiating with respect to $x$ and equating the derivative to $0$ (alternatively you can complete the square to find the apex). I think you can solve this from here.

Post a comment if you need further help.

Answer (score 0):

$x+y=80 \implies$

$y=80-x \implies$

$x^2+10x+120y=x^2+10x+120(80-x)=x^2-110x+960$

---

$f(x)=x^2-110x+960 \implies$

$f'(x)=2x-110 \implies$

$f''(x)=2$

---

$f'(x)=0 \implies$

$2x-110=0 \implies$

$x=55$

---

$f'(55)=0 \wedge f''(55)>0 \implies$

$x=55$ is a minimum point for $f(x)$

---

$x=55 \implies y=80-x=25$